# 1 point intersection problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator

problem 1: how do I draw/generate a line between 2 objects that touches these objects both perfectly in 1 point?

problem 2: how do I move an object horizontally/vertically until it touches another specific object in 1 point?

[image: to illustrate the problem]

Comment: This is a feature of CAD software and not so much Illustration software. There are plugins for Adobe Illustrator (or, at least, there were) that added some CAD features.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator hasn't snappings that find the wanted positions in your drawing scenes. CAD software has more snapping modes available and it's well possible that just those modes exist which solve your problems. Unfortunatly I cannot directly show which snaps in which software. I have only a couple of low cost commercial CAD program and freeware.

*EDIT: My CAD software have an automatic construction of the common tangent for two circular arcs. Otherwise it's not more helpful than Illustrator for your problems.*

If your shapes happen to be simple enough - such as circles - you can calculate the right tangent line or the needed horizontal or vertical shift. The calculations need not to be numerical. You can use elementary geometry and construct some help lines and circles that show the wanted positions. If you're lucky the wanted mathematical relations get fullfilled with auxiliary shapes which can be drawn exactly with Illustrator's snaps.

An example: Moving the circle

[image]

1. The green circle must be moved along the blue line. But to where?
2. We make a copy (=cyan) of the green circle. Ai's snap to points and smart quides help to position it perfectly tangentially to the rightmost point of the black circle. The anchor points snap together if you select the cyan circle and drag it's leftmost anchor point with the direct selection tool.
3. Draw a circle (magenta to the center of the black circle (hold Alt+Shift). The circle line snaps to the center of the cyan circle. Insert an anchor point to the crossing (=P) of the blue line and the magenta circle.
4. Drag the center of the green circle to P

Proof: P is at the wanted direction and at the wanted distance from the black circle.

The common tangent construction for 2 circles is a little more complex, but perfectly possible with Ai's snaps without any add-ons. I can insert the construction, if it's needed.

For complex shapes the problems must be solve approximately and then with a high zoom the position or placement must be adjusted until it's accurate enough.

Actually in CAD software the same happens underhood automatically. It's possible because the shapes are defined with mathematical relations and the perfect crossings can be solved iteratively as soon as an approximate solution is found.

In theory something helpful can be available as add-ons for Illustrator. Hopefully someone knows more and inserts it here or writes an answer.

EDIT: User @joojaa has added as a comment "The tangent finding is available in Hiruoki Satos scripts it is called common tangents i use it every day. A similar tool is also in subscribe plugin by astute graphics, its free. The second example can be done with illustrators native snapping tools."

Thanks for @joojaa ! I have asked him to show the general solution of the second problem, if possible. Hiruoki Satos's Common Tangents searches  the common tanget for complex curves, too, not only for circles.

Comment: The tangent finding is available in Hiruoki Satos scripts it is called common tangents i use it every day. A similar tool is also in subscribe plugin by astute graphics, its free. The second example can be done with illustrators native snapping tools.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for the quidance. Can you show the general (not circles only) solution of the second problem. At least I am iterested.